# Anchored Images and preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written a small script that allows users to search for images. There is a large main image and a number of thumbnails that are created and appended within the HTML when the search is submitted. The image files are remotely hosted and formatted by CSS. The main image should be replaced by whichever thumbnail that's clicked, but I can't seem to get it to work, nor is event.preventDefault() working. I have a feeling it's a problem with the jQuery selectors, but I've tried a number of different configurations and nothing. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div id="photos">
    <div id="mainImage">
        <a href="http://drive.google.com/pic1.jpg" target="_blank" class="main">
            <img src="http://drive.google.com/pic1.jpg" alt="Pic 1" />
        </a>  
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs">  
        <a href="http://drive.google.com/pic1.jpg" class="thumb">
            <img src="http://drive.google.com/pic1.jpg" alt="Pic 1" class="thumbnail"/>
        </a>
        <a href="http://drive.google.com/pic2.jpg" class="thumb">
            <img src="http://drive.google.com/pic2.jpg" alt="Pic 2" class="thumbnail"/>
        </a>
        <a href="http://drive.google.com/pic3.jpg" class="thumb">
            <img src="http://drive.google.com/pic3.jpg" alt="Pic 3" class="thumbnail"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>



$('a.thumb img.thumbnail').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var src = $('img.thumbnail').attr('src'), alt = $('img.thumbnail').attr('alt');

    $('a.main').attr('href', src);
    $('a.main img').attr({'src': src, 'alt': alt});  
});
```

Comment: You are preventing the default click event on the img, not the anchor. You may also need to use `event.stopPropagation()` to avoid the click from being passed on to the anchor. Also, your selectors `img.thumbnail` will return multiple results, you should limit your selector scope to $(this).

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but using 'event.stopPropagation()' made and makes no difference. 
I tried using 'this' before but, being Javascript, that obviously didn't work. Not seeing my error, I thought that I needed to specify with the actual selector and what you see is the result. So, thank you for clearing up selector scope.
It still doesn't want to work for some reason, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You should try this:

```
$('div#thumbs a.thumb').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var image = $(this).find('img');
    var src = image.attr('src');
    var alt = image.attr('alt');

    $('div#mainImage a.main').attr('href', src);
    $('div#mainImage a.main img').attr({'src': src, 'alt': alt});  
});
```

Firsly, You are preventing default CLICK action on image, not the anchor.
Secondly, using `$('img.thumbnail')` will return multiple objects in code.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and clearing up using $(this). 'this' is something that I tried before but I forgot to make it a jQuery object and so, like the above, it didn't work. I like the look of your solution better than mine, but it's still producing the same effect. On being clicked, the thumbnail redirects the page to its own address. I wonder if using a relative href would make a difference? Thanks, again for your help.

Comment: Not a problem :). Did You changed the selector from `$('a.thumb img.thumbnail')` to `$('a.thumb')` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the href values in the anchor tags. The script worked after their removal.